# Is it possible to rename a kibana value for better graph readablity?

Tags: logstash, kibana

Given the following data:

```js
records: [
  {id: 1, path: "www.somewebsite.com/en/landing.html" },
  {id: 2, path: "www.somewebsite.com/es/landing.html" },
]
```

is it possible to achieve a graph that shows (`English: 50%`|`Spanish: 50%`)?

It is possible to get the correct data split by using two filters:

```
logstash.records.path: */en/*
```

```
logstash.records.path: */es/*
```

but this still yeilds the messy labels: (`logstash.records.path: */en/*: 50%`|`logstash.records.path: */es/*: 50%`)

Comment: The `kql` tag stands for Kusto Query Language

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz Oops my mistake there, thanks for the correction!